# syntax of styling a react component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="card border-0 shadow " style={{margin: '0 500px' }}>
```

The above code describes how to add margins to a component ,but why can't it be written like this:

```
<div className="card border-0 shadow " style={{top-margin: '500px';left-margin : '200px' }}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style syntax is wrong, replace `;` with `,` to make it a valid object. Also object keys should be in camelCase.

Example:

`style={{ marginTop: '500px', marginLeft: '200px' }}`

Comment: i am following this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp ...we have properties named as margin-top
margin-right
margin-bottom
margin-left , but from where have you got this property 'marginTop' ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're writing in JSX syntax which means you need to pass an object to the style attribute/prop. These object keys need to be in camelCase notation. You can use CSS classes and add them in the `className` name attribute as well or just use `styled-components`.

Comment: Note they don't actually _need_ to be `camelCase` - `kebab-case` isn't syntatically valid in JS, so that's out, but they could be e.g. `snake_case`. They just have to be valid identifiers. Alternatively they can be quoted, `"kebab-case"` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write it like this

```
<div className="card border-0 shadow " style={{marginTo: '500px';left-margin : '200px' }}>
```